# Updating Plain Data to Encrypted via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

With the new GDPR rules coming into place in the EU I'm looking to update a very simple event booking system from a plain file database to an encrypted database.

My database already has encryption for the admins to login, but I plan on using `AES_ENCRYPT` for the people who we make the bookings for.

Currently, we store `firstname`, `surname`, `email` and `telephone` in a table called `event_candidate` and I know how to call and update a single row, but I need some advice on how to batch update all rows in the database.

Heres my thrown together version. I know it isn't correct, but any advice or guidance on how to make this run as a single batch updating script would be greatly appreciated.

```
$key = "insert_key_here";

$Get_Details = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT id, firstname, surname, telephone, email FROM event_candidate');
$Get_Details->execute();
if($Get_Details->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach ($Get_Details->fetchAll() as $Get_Details_Row) { 

    // Run the update
    $Update_Details = $dbconn->prepare('UPDATE event_candidate SET 
                                        firstname = AES_ENCRYPT(:firstname,'.$key.'), 
                                        surname = AES_ENCRYPT(:surname,'.$key.'), 
                                        telephone = AES_ENCRYPT(:telephone,'.$key.'), 
                                        email = AES_ENCRYPT(:email,'.$key.') 
                                        WHERE id = :id');
    $Update_Details->bindParam(':id', $Get_Details_Row['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $Update_Details->bindParam(':firstname', $Get_Details_Row['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $Update_Details->bindParam(':surname', $Get_Details_Row['surname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $Update_Details->bindParam(':telephone', $Get_Details_Row['telephone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $Update_Details->bindParam(':email', $Get_Details_Row['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($Update_Details->execute()) {
        // It worked!
    } else {
        // Error Checking
    }

    } 

} else {
    // Error Checking
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `UPDATE event_candidate SET firstname=aes_encrypt(firstname,'YOUR_KEY'), surname=aes_encrypt(surname,'YOUR_KEY'), ....;` work for you? It should encrypt all fields in one batch.